# Need to put @Overrides Methods for Android Life Cycle in Each Class or Just in the Main Class

Tags: android

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    notify("onCreate");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    notify("onPause");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notify("onResume");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    notify("onStop");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    notify("onDestroy");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    notify("onRestoreInstanceState");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    notify("onSaveInstanceState");
  }
```

I'm if right, these are the methods to handle the life cycle of an activity. My question is, do you need to put these methods in each class if you want to handle your app life cycle properly, or just in the main class?

Comment: It depends on your need. You may not need to put all these methods in your main class also .

Comment: It's Activity Life Cycle not Android Life Cycle. So you have to handle it in every Activity according to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have to be implemented once *per activity*. The code of one activity won't be used in anotherone unless the second is a subclass of the first.

As an additional note, only `onCreate` *must* be implemented, the others are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to override the methods that you want to use.

If you don't need to perform any special functions in `onDestroy()`, for example, you don't need to override it in any of your Activities.

A good way to identify whether or not you need it is to look at what you have in those methods. If all you are doing is calling `super`, then you don't need to include that method in your Activity because the default behavior will work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to develop some certain behavior that can be applied to some specific part of the life cycle you have to put those methods in each class Activity. Because of the inheritance that a class have if you want some specific behavior through all the app I recommend you to use the Application class that modifies all the subsequent Activities the only problem is that not all the normal methods of an activity life cycle are available.

Here is some reference about lifecycle in Application class:

https://www.inkling.com/read/programming-android-mednieks-1st/chapter-11/life-cycle-methods-of-the

The best example of the method you always have to override is onCreate() because here is where you add all the normal start up behavior of the views and logic in your activity.

**If you are not very well acquainted with android life cycle I do not recommend you to override these methods because they can lead you to strange behavior in your app, that is for my personal experience.**